# Attempted import of apache_beam in python3 on Mac throws fatal protobuf error

Tags: mac, python

Trying to import apache_beam

```
>>> import apache_beam
```

throws a fatal error

> [libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:58] File already exists in database:
>   [libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1370] CHECK failed:
>   GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size):
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException:
>   CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size):

I've managed to reproduce this with a `virtualenv` created using `pyenv` and through the system installed python.

From other posts I've gathered that this is an issue with `libprotobuf` being loaded twice. I'm bothered by the fact that the first ERROR is not reporting which file exists in the database, though.

Running `python -v` indicates that the issue is connected with `pyarrow`, which is the last dependency imported by apache_beam before it bombs. I did try installing pyarrow prior to apache_beam, and it loaded fine. However, apache_beam uninstalls and then re-installs it, presumably leading to the linker error.

Any advice on how to get apache_beam working?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have recently upgraded your macos to Catalina then this error is caused by pyarrow (already reported under https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8368)

The temporary solution is pinning pyarrow < 0.14.0

Comment: Yes, it was caused by the OS upgrade. Downgrading pyarrow has fixed it. Thanks for the advice.